# How to fill color layer/YAxis in MPAndroidChart Radar chart?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mpandroidchart, radar-chart

I wanna fill 5 other colors by layer/section like photo with Radar chart(MPAndroidChart).
Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

[image: mpandroidchart radar chart]https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPiQC.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version MPAndroidChart(3.1.0), but you can download their code and make your own logic. I could make a demo for you, it's very simple:

before change the library code:
[image]

after change the library code:
[image]

code change is list here on github:
[github](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/pull/5273/files)

And the demo code is:

```
    radarChart = findViewById(R.id.radar);
    List<RadarEntry> radarEntryList = new ArrayList<>();
    radarEntryList.add(new RadarEntry(20));
    radarEntryList.add(new RadarEntry(30));
    radarEntryList.add(new RadarEntry(35));
    radarEntryList.add(new RadarEntry(40));
    radarEntryList.add(new RadarEntry(60));

    RadarDataSet radarDataSet = new RadarDataSet(radarEntryList, "test");
    RadarData radarData = new RadarData(radarDataSet);
    radarChart.setData(radarData);
    List<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    colorList.add(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    colorList.add(Color.rgb(222, 166, 111));
    colorList.add(Color.rgb(220, 206, 138));
    colorList.add(Color.rgb(243, 255, 192));
    colorList.add(Color.rgb(240, 255, 240));
    colorList.add(Color.rgb(250, 255, 250));
    radarChart.setLayerColorList(colorList);
```

Comment: Demo code set 5 layer color but chart show only 4, miss first color. How to show 5 layer color and grid line before change lib? Thanks.

Comment: @tienminh has update the demo code, update the github code later.

Comment: thank @penkzhou. I look forward to the github update.

Comment: @tienminh the github code is update, you can check it out.

Comment: thanks for update code. But grid line (spider web) seem hidden by background color layer. How to visible it with background color layers? Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPiQC.png